# how to use alias in querydsl?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, querydsl

I am new to querydsl and already in love with it, but I can't get how to use an alias in this query.

```
    QProduct product = QProduct.product;
    JPQLQuery jPQLQuery = 
            from(product)
            .where(product.name.locate(searchTerm).as("score").gt(0).or(product.code.locate(searchTerm).as("score").gt(0))).groupBy(product.baseProd);
    List<Product> matchedNames = jPQLQuery.orderBy(new NumberPath<Integer>(Integer.class, "score").asc()).offset((pageNumber-1)*10).limit(10).list(product);
```

my first thought was something like this which throws an error with the generated query as:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:
>   as near line 3, column 31 [select product from
>   mesoft.meshopframework.model.Product product where
>   locate(?1,product.name) as score > ?2 or locate(?1,product.code) as
>   score > ?2 group by product.baseProd order by score asc]

could someone show me the coorect way to do this?? I hope it's not necessary for DB to calculate `product.name.locate(searchTerm)` or the other one again for sorting,

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPQL has a more restricted syntax compared to SQL, but I don't think your example would work in SQL either.

You can't use aliases in the where part and for order you will need pick one of the locate expressions or order by both of them.

Comment: yea, I tried to sort with a locate expression. But since I'm new to the querying world altogether and I see you're not, may I ask "does that mean the DB engine will calculate the locate expression again for sorting? and any way to avoid that??"

Comment: The recalculation aspect depends on your DB engine. Which one do you use?